# Beautiful soup: Extracting url from webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm struggling to extract  highlighted URL from a web page using beautiful soup.
[image]

Following is what I have tried

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

finalURL = https://auto.mahindra.com/search?s=mahindra%20thar

# Get the web page
response = requests.get(finalURL)

# Parse the web page using Beautiful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

# Find the element with class "pages-content"
pages_content = soup.find("div", attrs={"class": "pages-content"})

# Find all "a" elements inside the element
links = pages_content.find_all('a')

# Print the text of all the "a" elements
for link in links:
    print(link.get('href'))

print("********************************************")
```

Following is output

```
$Url
$UrlReadMore
********************************************
```

Here is the snippet from source code

```
$Image
<div class="pages-content">
<a href="$Url" class="content-heading">$Title</a>
<div class="pages-dscp">
<p>$PublishDate</p>
<p>$Description</p>
</div>
<a href="$UrlReadMore" class="content-read-more">Read More</a>
</div>
```

From the source code it look like an expected response. so, I am looking for suggestions how to extract the url highlighted in image above.

Page url: https://auto.mahindra.com/search?s=mahindra%20thar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `post` endpoints and pass the page number, I have added 10 only, which will return output in `json` format

> https://auto.mahindra.com/api/search

```
import requests
baseURL='https://auto.mahindra.com'
for page in range(10):
    header={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    url="https://auto.mahindra.com/api/search"
    data={
     "query": "mahindra thar",
     "page": page,
     "type": "pages"
        }
    response=requests.post(url,data=data,headers=header,cookies ={'cookie' :'TiPMix=92.16225552429106; x-ms-routing-name=self; mahindra#lang=en; is_935832=false; is_ExitPopup=false; is_023273=false; sxa_site=Mahindra-Preview; first_load_done=true; _gcl_au=1.1.127606886.1676992228; _gid=GA1.2.1092194852.1676992228; _fbp=fb.1.1676992228268.858271736; isiframeenabled=true; ASP.NET_SessionId=n5rd0jdydjtv0ciugxxidkqp; _hjFirstSeen=1; _hjIncludedInSessionSample_1831298=0; _hjSession_1831298=eyJpZCI6IjM5OTk4M2FlLTY3NWItNGVjYi04MjM0LTg5MTM5OTdjN2Y0ZCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NzY5OTIyMjk5NzQsImluU2FtcGxlIjpmYWxzZX0=; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=0; mahindramahindraltd-_zldp=I27V8fgtaNlDKXVEz+YGxYciCxCAtRWF+jztSDbVJ3LwNdfDRxpun09v3YEfdrAmEKBPNwTNF2c=; mahindramahindraltd-_zldt=261d336b-b1c6-4c30-be4d-fc87f9b7147c-2; privacy-notification=1; _ga_NKE3LP8V8N=GS1.1.1676992228.1.1.1676992288.60.0.0; _hjSessionUser_1831298=eyJpZCI6IjZkMzgyYzljLWQxNWItNTMyZi05YmRmLWI0M2ZjNmYxOThhYiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NzY5OTIyMjg0MTEsImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; _ga=GA1.2.2032021514.1676992228; QSI_SI_eXu0qbAYZqg4CUK_intercept=true; _gat_UA-153588006-1=1'}).json()
    print("data for page {}".format(page+1))
    for item in response['Pages']:
           print(baseURL+item['Url'])
    print("===========================")
```

**Output:**

```
data for page 1
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/test-drive
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/gallery
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/specifications-features
https://auto.mahindra.com/the-thar-film-contest-terms
https://auto.mahindra.com/events-dummy/all-new-thar-auction
https://auto.mahindra.com/service-action/thar-service-action
https://auto.mahindra.com/events/all-new-thar-auction
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/thar/test-drive
===========================
data for page 2
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/maxx-pik-up
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/pik-up-fish-carrier-application
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/pik-up-medicine-carrier-application
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/pik-up-lpg-carrier-application
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/p113-application-3
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/p113-application-1
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/p113-application-2
https://auto.mahindra.com/personalizationtest
https://auto.mahindra.com/electric/zor-grand/electric-enquire
===========================
data for page 3
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/book-bolero-online
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/locate-us
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/gallary
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/build-and-price
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/features-specs
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/book-a-test-drive
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/compare-variants
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/bolero-new
https://auto.mahindra.com/pages/bolero/gallary-new
https://auto.mahindra.com/electric/treo-zor
===========================
data for page 4
https://auto.mahindra.com/electric/zor-grand
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/xuv500
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/alturasg4
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/marazzo
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/bolero
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/scorpio
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/copy-xuv
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/maxx-pik-up/feature-and-specifications
https://auto.mahindra.com/electric/treo-zor/specifications-features
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/feature-and-specifications
===========================
data for page 5
https://auto.mahindra.com/service-action-changed
https://auto.mahindra.com/qms-certificates
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/maxx-pik-up/fruits-n-vegetables-application/offers-schemes
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/gallery
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/faqs
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/pik-up-fish-carrier-application/offers-schemes
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/pik-up-fish-carrier-application/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/maxx-pik-up/fruits-n-vegetables-application/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/pik-up-medicine-carrier-application/offers-schemes
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/pik-up-lpg-carrier-application/user-reviews
===========================
data for page 6
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/bolero-pik-up/pik-up-lpg-carrier-application/offers-schemes
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/p113-application-3/offers-schemes
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/p113-application-1/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/p113-application-1/offers-schemes
https://auto.mahindra.com/press-release
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/p113-application-2/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/pick-up-trucks/p113-test-thar/p113-application-2/offers-schemes
https://auto.mahindra.com/service-action
https://auto.mahindra.com/careers
https://auto.mahindra.com/service-action/marazzo-service-action
===========================
data for page 7
https://auto.mahindra.com/service-action/xuv300-suspension-component
https://auto.mahindra.com/personalizationtest/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/service-action/scorpio-service-action
https://auto.mahindra.com/personalizationtest/specifications-features
https://auto.mahindra.com/personalizationtest/faqs
https://auto.mahindra.com/showroom-at-home
https://auto.mahindra.com/service-action-tab
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/kuv100-nxt/faqs
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/kuv100-nxt/gallery
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/kuv100-nxt/testimonials
===========================
data for page 8
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/alturas-g4/test-drive
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/alturas-g4/faqs
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/kuv100-nxt/specifications-features
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/alturas-g4/specifications-features
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/alturas-g4/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/alturas-g4/gallery
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/marazzo/faqs
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/marazzo/test-drive
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/marazzo/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/marazzo/gallery
===========================
data for page 9
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/marazzo/specifications-features
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/scorpio/test-drive
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/scorpio/gallery
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/scorpio/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/scorpio/specifications-features
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/scorpio/faqs
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/bolero/test-drive
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/bolero/faqs
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/bolero/specifications-features
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/bolero/gallery
===========================
data for page 10
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/bolero/user-reviews
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/homepage/xuv700/press-release
https://auto.mahindra.com/suv/homepage/xuv700/faqs
https://auto.mahindra.com/terms-of-use
https://auto.mahindra.com/finance-disclaimer
https://auto.mahindra.com/media-kit
https://auto.mahindra.com/apps-download
https://auto.mahindra.com/about-us
https://auto.mahindra.com/events
https://auto.mahindra.com/events-dummy/freedom-drive
===========================
```